# How to make a probability simulator in R?

Tags: r, simulation, probability

With the following data frame:

```
A1  A2  EFF       FRQ      
A   G   0.0125    0.4578  
T   C   0.0143    0.1293    
T   C   -0.017    0.8984  
A   G   -0.018    0.8945   
A   G   -0.009    0.8652   
A   G   0.0001    0.3931
```

I would like to make two probability "draws" from the effect size based on the `FRQ` column. I want to make a new column called `sim_1` where 45.78% of the time, the `EFF` keeps it's sign, and where 54.22% of the time, the `EFF` switches it's sign. I would like to then sum two of these random events for each row. For example, let's say that two random numbers 0-100 are generated. 78.33 and 32.16. I will take anything < 45.78 as being indicative of keeping the `EFF` the same. Since I randomly rolled a 78 and 32, the sum will be -0.0125 (for the 78.33 roll) and 0.0125 for the (32.16) roll, which equals 0.

In the second row, let's say that I roll two random numbers of 88.22 and 67.10. Because neither of these numbers are below 12.93, then the `EFF` sign will be flipped for both the 88.22 and 67.10 roll, leaving us with a sum of -0.0286 (-0.0143 + -0.0143).

I would like to do 500 simulation columns in this manner so that the final output looks like:

```
A1  A2  EFF       FRQ      Sim_1   Sim_2   Sim_3...
A   G   0.0125    0.4578   0       -       -
T   C   0.0143    0.1293   -0.0286 -       -
T   C   -0.017    0.8984  -        -       -
A   G   -0.018    0.8945  -        -       -
A   G   -0.009    0.8652  -        -       -
A   G   0.0001    0.3931  -        -       -
```

Note: If you generate an output file, it may not match mine since it is based on randomness.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your data:

```
tmp_df <- structure(list(A1 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), 
                                        .Label = c("A", "T"), class = "factor"), 
                         A2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L),
                                        .Label = c("C", "G"), class = "factor"), 
                         EFF = c(0.0125, 0.0143, -0.017, -0.018, -0.009, 1e-04), 
                         FRQ = c(0.4578, 0.1293, 0.8984, 0.8945, 0.8652, 0.3931)),
                    .Names = c("A1", "A2", "EFF", "FRQ"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Do the following

```
set.seed(0)

tmp_results <- lapply(1:500, function(i) rowSums(2 * (0.5 - (matrix(runif(nrow(tmp_df) * 2), ncol = 2) >= tmp_df$FRQ)) * tmp_df$EFF))



tmp_out <- as.data.frame(tmp_results)
names(tmp_out) <- paste("Sim", 1:500)

tmp_out <- cbind(tmp_df, tmp_out)
```

producing:

```
> tmp_out[, 1:10]
  A1 A2     EFF    FRQ   Sim 1   Sim 2   Sim 3   Sim 4   Sim 5   Sim 6
1  A  G  0.0125 0.4578 -0.0250  0.0000  0.0250 -0.0250  0.0000  0.0250
2  T  C  0.0143 0.1293 -0.0286 -0.0286 -0.0286 -0.0286  0.0000 -0.0286
3  T  C -0.0170 0.8984 -0.0340 -0.0340 -0.0340 -0.0340 -0.0340 -0.0340
4  A  G -0.0180 0.8945 -0.0360  0.0000 -0.0360 -0.0360 -0.0360 -0.0360
5  A  G -0.0090 0.8652  0.0000 -0.0180 -0.0180 -0.0180 -0.0180  0.0000
6  A  G  0.0001 0.3931  0.0002 -0.0002 -0.0002  0.0000 -0.0002  0.0000
```

Explanation of the `lapply` step:

```
1) matrix(runif(nrow(tmp_df) * 2)
Draw two columns filled with random numbers drawn uniformly in the interval [0, 1].
Alternatively, you can look into using `rbinom`.

2) 2 * (... >= tmp_df$FRQ) * tmp_df$EFF
Create (-1, 1) indicator to see whether `EFF` should be fliped, then multiply, exploiting conformability rules.

3) lapply(...) 
Do the above 500 times.
```

The rest simply label, and bind the simulated results to your original data.

Comment: The line `tmp_results <- lapply(1:500, function(i) rowSums(2 * (0.5 - matrix(runif(nrow(tmp_df) * 2), ncol = 2) >= tmp_df$FRQ) * tmp_df$EFF))
(tmp_results)` is outputting millions of lines into my R and crashing my program

Comment: sorry about that, not sure how the `(tmp_results)` appeared. Just delete it, as this is printing all the results.

Comment: there are some simulations for the second row where I am getting 0.05758 (essentially 4x the effect column). Do you know why that could be happening? The simulation should never give more than double the value of the effect size in magnitude.

Comment: sorry, I put the bracket in the wrong place when trying to make the indicator function. Fixed now, I hope.